# How to extract Audio Record data form Sound[SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"] ?

Tags: sound, data-acquisition

[image]
When I set parameter `"SoundReg"` to collect Audio Steaming data - it's working 
[image]

After that I use `Button\["Record"\]` In my `Manipulate[]`

```
Style\["Audio Record", Bold, 18, FontFamily -> Times\],

Button\["Record", Sound\[SystemDialogInput\["RecordSound"\]\]\],
```

To show you

```
Button\["Record", AudioRec = Sound\[SystemDialogInput\["RecordSound"\]\]\],
```

but when I try to declare some parameter to keep `Audio` data, the parameter does not appear anywhere and I assume the Audio Streaming data may be stored somewhere else.

Comment: You want to extract the data, but you are `Import[]`-ing the recording ? Please, clarify.

Comment: Try adding `Method -> "Queued"` to the `Button`. The evaluation is probably timing out on the preemptive link.

Comment: @SimonWoods or worse, perhaps the SystemDialogInput requires the preemptive link to work but it's busy on the button. So it only starts working after the timeout of the button frees the link. But it will never assign to AudioRec because that evaluation was cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

I try to fix it and this is my result 
[image]
This is my code
[image]
"AudioRec" Parameter can be collected with declare in Dynamic Module Part .Like this situation but I can't Separate each graph to show on dynamic Module. when I try to get comma and {} out. It doesn't work anything 
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful to others if you posted the code in a text (copyable) format rather than images.